# Expanding obout.com ASP.NET TreeView from Delphi WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, delphi, browser

I have a website using this a treeview component:

http://www.obout.com/t2/ex_expand_levels.aspx

I need expand all nodes of the treeview.I DONT have the buttons (nor the functions) just the treeview itself. (Please find the code sample below)

I have loaded the page and able to send JavaScript to the website, but have not been able to simulate click on the "+" signs to expand a nodes. I have got several.

I would really like to see a simple example code if possible in Delphi.

The Delphi code I am using to exec the Javascript is the following:

My form got a WebBrowser, an Edit and a Button:

```
uses MSHTML;

procedure TForm1.ButtonJSButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  { Make browser exec JS }
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;      // current HTML document
  HTMLWindow: IHTMLWindow2; // parent window of current HTML document
  JSFn: string;             // stores JavaScipt function call
begin

  // Get reference to current document
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if not Assigned(Doc) then
    Exit;
  // Get parent window of current document
  HTMLWindow := Doc.parentWindow;
  if not Assigned(HTMLWindow) then
    Exit;
  // Run JavaScript
  try
    JSFn := Edit1.Text;
    HTMLWindow.execScript(JSFn, 'JavaScript');
  except
    // handle exception in case JavaScript fails to run
    ShowMessage('Error running JavaScript |'+Edit1.Text+'|');
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance,

Zsolt

JavaScript:

```
<!--   ASP TreeView component   http://www.obout.com   -->



<LINK REL=stylesheet HREF="/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/obout_treeview.css" > 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var op2, ob_tb, ob_url, selected_node_id;
function ob_wk(os, url) {
    var ot = os.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling;
    var lensrc = (os.src.length - 8);
    var s = os.src.substr(lensrc, 8);
    if (s == "inus.gif") {
        ot.style.display = "none";
        os.src = "/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/plusik.gif";
    }
    if (s == "usik.gif") {
        ot.style.display = "block";
        os.src = "/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/minus.gif";
    if (url != "") {
        var s = os.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.innerText;
        if (s != "Loading ...") {
            return;
        }
        ob_url = url;
        ob_tb = os;
        window.setTimeout("ob_tm()", 100);
    }
    }
}

function ob_tm() {
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("GET", ob_url, false);
    xmlhttp.send("");
    ob_tb.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.outerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}

function ob_ft(e) {
    if (e.tagName == "TABLE" && e.className == "ob_zz") {
        if (typeof op2 != "undefined") {
            op2.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            op2.style.border = "0px solid #999999";
            op2.style.margin = "1px";
        }
        e.style.backgroundColor = "#E6E6E6";
        e.style.border = "0px solid #aaceeb";
        e.style.margin = "0px";
        op2 = e;
        selected_node_id = e.children(0).children(0).children(1).id;
    }
    else {
        ob_ft(e.parentNode);
    }
}

function ob_os(e){
    var os = e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children(0).children(0);
    if (os != null) {
    if ((typeof os != "undefined") && (os.tagName == "IMG")) {
        var lensrc = (os.src.length - 8);
        var s = os.src.substr(lensrc, 8);
        if ((s == "inus.gif") || (s == "usik.gif")) {
            e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children(0).children(0).click();
        }
    }
    else {
        ob_os(e.parentNode);
    }
}}

//-->
</SCRIPT>




<!--   ASP TreeView component   http://www.obout.com   -->



<div id="divTree" name="divTree" style="background:;background-image: url('');overflow-X:auto; overflow-Y:auto; width:; height:;"><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:block;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img class=ob_ic src='/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/minus.gif' onclick="ob_wk(this, '')"></td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpGlobe.gif'></td><td id=a0 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td>Root</td></tr></table><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:block;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img class=ob_ic src='/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/plusik.gif' onclick="ob_wk(this, '')"></td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/folder.gif'></td><td id=b1 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><SPAN onclick='ob_os(this)'>TREE</SPAN></td></tr></table><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:none;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img class=ob_ic src='/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/plusik.gif' onclick="ob_wk(this, '')"></td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpHome.gif'></td><td id=c1 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><SPAN onclick='ob_os(this)'>Site1</SPAN></td></tr></table><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:none;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic>&nbsp;</td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpPanel.gif'></td><td id=d1 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><input type=checkbox name=sIteID value=1_DD32B129-527A-42FA-A0D0-FE3C0ED65BC5><STRONG>Site1>Unit1</STRONG><input type=hidden name=sup_ value={DD32B129-527A-42FA-A0D0-FE3C0ED65BC5}></td><td align=right></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img class=ob_ic src='/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/plusik.gif' onclick="ob_wk(this, '')"></td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpHome.gif'></td><td id=c2 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><SPAN onclick='ob_os(this)'>Site2</SPAN></td></tr></table><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:none;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic>&nbsp;</td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpPanel.gif'></td><td id=d2 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><input type=checkbox name=sIteID value=2_E6DC2021-F8E9-4FBE-93F5-79C953FA7BA8><STRONG>Site2>Unit2</STRONG><input type=hidden name=sup_ value={E6DC2021-F8E9-4FBE-93F5-79C953FA7BA8}></td><td align=right></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img class=ob_ic src='/_tree/treeStyle_Explorer/plusik.gif' onclick="ob_wk(this, '')"></td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpHome.gif'></td><td id=c3 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><SPAN onclick='ob_os(this)'>Site3</SPAN></td></tr></table><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="display:none;"><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic>&nbsp;</td><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=ob_zz><tr><td width=1 class=ob_ic><img width=16 class=ob_ic src='/_tree/xpPanel.gif'></td><td id=d3 onclick='ob_ft(this)' class=ob_td><input type=checkbox name=sIteID value=3_01B94E4C-A21A-4C76-920E-C2B9773CE2B8><STRONG>Site3>Unit3</STRONG><input type=hidden name=sup_ value={01B94E4C-A21A-4C76-920E-C2B9773CE2B8}></td><td align=right></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
ob_ft(b1);
 //--></script>


<!--   ASP TreeView component   http://www.obout.com   -->
```

Comment: This is a vendor support question. You should be asking them using their [Support Page](http://www.obout.com/inc/support.aspx). Also, two minutes browsing their KnowledgeBase found [Expand or collapse all nodes at once](http://www.obout.com/t2/KnowledgeBase.aspx?id=492). Voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: ".I DONT have the buttons (nor the functions) just the treeview itself." = in the code that site I need to open nodes DOES NOT HAVE nor the function neither the button to "Collapse all nodes". I dont think the vendor would be able to answer my question...

Comment: @Ken: I included the code for the treeview I need to deal with... "ob_tall(1);" I tried to exec it on my treeview, but did not work. I did not yet find any real solution to do the same... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Delphi? All your code is JavaScript...

Comment: @Jeroen: I would like to send the Exec a Javascript (Simulate a click on the nodes) from Delphi from a WebBrowser component, since the website only works in Internet Explorer. I would be happy not to use Javascript at all, If you want I can include Delphi Code too...

Comment: @user1587839 please do, as that might give people some insight on where to put the tree expansion code.

Comment: I added the code, if you just save the javascript bit as sample.html and on Form1.Onreate do WebBrowser.Navigate('sample.html') then you should be able to see my issue finally. Thanks again.

Comment: Then that is the question to ask, how to click in internet explorer form Delphi.
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+javascript http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+click+webbrowser&submit=search

Comment: @Arioch: thats not really the question, I am able to run javascript, I would just need to know what functions needed to be called.

Comment: Then open the URL u given at top and look at those Collapse X / Expend Y buttons. What the JS code do they run? inspect and do the same.

Comment: @Arioc: There is no BUTTONS in the html I get from the website... Anyhow I might found way around the problem: Basically I need to get all text part and links from each page and decide which checkboxes to click...

Comment: i don't know what is your browser, if it is modern, if it does not corrupt page source by spam/advertisement killers, etc. I can only say that i DO see buttons at the very page u linked to: http://imgur.com/tqiqc

Comment: @Arioch'The Sorry, Bro! Should have been more clear I guess. I added that first link as an example. Tought it will make it easier. The second code that I added (you can save it as an .html) at the end of the question thats what I get from the website. (imho its a modified version of the treeview component). There is no button, or function that I am able to call there...

Comment: Who cares! that is the same tree and the same code works.
I repeat: you should not click the buttons! you should learn javascript code, that executed when u click the buttons. The js code that does the expansion collapsing after button click. And then you should use that js code either injected to ur page or translated to Delphi. you should read onClick handlers of those buttons and use that as a sample for your application.

Comment: I am not very good with javascript, but I will try to do that, I tought posting it, some point out how to do that actually. Some other parts of the same site I managed to understand with Chrome, but these parts of the site just does not work in IE. Any suggestions for tools like the Dev Tools in Chrome?